# gocr - convert .jpg to .txt file

Tags: terminal

What command carries out the converting from .jpg to .txt in gocr? I can't find it in any examples https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-gocr/ . Thank you

Comment: Is `gocr image.jpg > text.txt` not working as expected? Where are you stuck?

Comment: It works, thank you very much

Comment: Can you please write a short answer? You can accept your own answer after 2 days. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thank you!